# Javascript regex - replace single character

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace all ONLY single equal signs.

```
var mystr = 'ONE == TWO ... THREE==FOUR ... FIVE = SIX ... SEVEN=EIGHT' ... NINE := TEN;
return mystr.replace(/(?=\=)([=]{1})(?!\=)/gm, '==');
```

I get the following:

```
ONE === TWO ... THREE===FOUR ... FIVE == SIX ... SEVEN==EIGHT ... NINE :== TEN
```

Numbers 5-6, 7-8, are ok. But, I would like this:

```
ONE == TWO ... THREE==FOUR ... FIVE == SIX ... SEVEN==EIGHT ... NINE := TEN
```

Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: Your regex does nothing to try and recognize the `:`. So, how could it possibly know not to duplicate the last `=` character? (Hint: since JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind assertions this is pretty tricky... the easiest way would be a second pass to replace `:==` with `:=`.)

Comment: FYI, `([=]{1})` is the same as `([=])` is the same as `(=)` (parenthesis are not even needed here). Don't make it overly complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Since Javascript doesn't support lookbehind assertions you can't check if the char before is an equal char or not. But you could match it an insert it again.

```
return mystr.replace(/([^=:])=(?!=)/g, '$1==');
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?356ut).

`([^=:])` is a negated character class, that matches any char, but = and :
. This char is reinserted in the replacement string by the `$1`.

This would not work, when the first char in the string is a single "=", since the start of the string would not be matched by `[^=:]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use this regex:

```
([^=:])=(?!=)
```

So this will match something that starts with anything not being `=` or `:` and then an `=` sign and no `=` after.

Then use a replace of `$1==`.

Tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/aN1dA6)

And if you want a picture too...

[image: Regular expression image]